# Há como fazer uma div filho, flutuar ao rolar o scroll da div pai?

Tags: javascript, css, div, rolamento

Tenho uma `div` primária, e dentro desta, outra `div`(secundária).

Estou tentando posicionar a `div` secundária na `div` primária de modo que, torne uma DIV flutuante(estilo popup) que sobreponha aos demais elementos.

Mas para este caso em especial, quero fazer sobrepor ao conteúdo da `div` principal e ao rolar o `Scroll` a `div` filho deve acompanhar.

Segue abaixo o código.

```css
#Pai {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
 height: 200px;
 border: 3px solid blue;
 text-align: center;
 overflow: auto;
}

#Filho {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 margin-left: -50px;
 /* metade da largura */
 margin-top: -50px;
 /* metade da altura */
 position: absolute;
 top: 50% ;
 left: 50% ;
 background: tomato;
 z-index: 1; // sobrepor
 -moz-opacity: 0.8;
 opacity: .80;
 filter: alpha(opacity = 80);
}
```

```html
<div id='Pai'>
  
 <p>Elemento A</p>
    <p>Elemento B</p>
    <p>Elemento C</p>
    <p>Elemento D</p>
    <p>Elemento E</p>
    <p>Elemento F</p>
    <p>Elemento G</p>
    <p>Elemento H</p>
    <p>Elemento I</p>
    <p>Elemento J</p>

    <div id='Filho'></div>

</div>
```

Teria como desenvolver um `Script` para conseguir este efeito, sem que precise alterar toda sintaxe do `CSS`?

## Por exemplo

```
var scrolldellay = document.getElementById("Pai");

   scrolldellay.scrollBy = function() {
                  ...
    // Coloque a rotina implementada
                  ...
 }
```

Comment: Modificando o `position:absolute;` para `position:fixed;` não serve para o seu caso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com as repostas que obtive de [Mathias](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/67721/mathias) e seguida de [Tobias Mesquita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/2363/tobias-mesquita), antes da sua nova edição.

Cheguei a duas alternativa similares, acredito que seja Cross-Browser.

1.ª_Alternativa

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>JS Bin</title>

<style type="text/css">

body {
        height: 999px;
}

#Pai {
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 3px solid blue;
       text-align: center;
       overflow: auto;
}

#Filho {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        margin-left: -50px;
        /* metade da largura */
        margin-top: -50px;
        /* metade da altura */
        position: absolute;
        top: 50% ;
        left: 50% ;
        background: tomato;
        z-index: 1;
        opacity: .80;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
<center>

<div id='Pai' onscroll = "rolamento()">

        <p>Elemento A</p>
        <p>Elemento B</p>
        <p>Elemento C</p>
        <p>Elemento D</p>
        <p>Elemento E</p>
        <p>Elemento F</p>
        <p>Elemento G</p>
        <p>Elemento H</p>
        <p>Elemento I</p>
        <p>Elemento J</p>

     <div id='Filho'></div>

</div>

</center>
<script type="text/javascript">

var A = document.getElementById('Pai'); 
var B = document.getElementById('Filho'); 

var rolamento = function() {    
    var centralizado = A.scrollTop + 100; 
    B.style.top = centralizado; 
}

A.onscroll = rolamento;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

## Segue Explicação

```
var A = document.getElementById('Pai'); // Div(primária)

var B = document.getElementById('Filho'); // Div(secundária)

var rolamento = function() {

        var centralizado = A.scrollTop + 100; // Aqui definimos o valor 100 para reposicionar a Div(secundária) conforme o valor scrollTop() da Div(primária) 
        B.style.top = centralizado; // Agora vamos automatizar a Div(secundária), para retomar sempre a mesma posição inicial

}

A.onscroll = rolamento; // Escuta o evento da barra de rolagem lateral e dispara a função
```

> **NOTA** - *"Esta 1.ª_Alternativa funcionou perfeitamente no Computador local, mas não teve o mesmo desfeixo quando tentei adicionar como amostra no http://jsbin.com/ e http://jsfiddle.net/. No entanto o Script em si, funciona, estando abaixo do `</body>`. Qualquer coisa que venha a ser, a causa, é de natureza desconhecida por mim."*

---

2.ª_Alternativa

```js
var A = document.getElementById('Pai');  // Div(primária)
var B = document.getElementById('Filho'); // Div(secundária)
var P = B.scrollHeight / 2;
A.onscroll = new Function("if(B.style.top = A.scrollTop + P + 'px') return true");
```

```css
body {
    height: 999px;
}

#Pai {
   position: relative;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   border: 3px solid blue;
   text-align: center;
   overflow: auto;
}

#Filho {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<center>

<div id='Pai'>

    <p>Elemento A</p>
    <p>Elemento B</p>
    <p>Elemento C</p>
    <p>Elemento D</p>
    <p>Elemento E</p>
    <p>Elemento F</p>
    <p>Elemento G</p>
    <p>Elemento H</p>
    <p>Elemento I</p>
    <p>Elemento J</p>

 <div id='Filho'></div>

</div>

</center>
```

**JSbin** - [Amostra externa](http://jsbin.com/rihaqasuza/embed?html,css,js,console,output)

## Explicando

```
var P = B.scrollHeight / 2;
```

Estou fazendo a divisão da `div`(secundária), por seu Tamanho real, ou seja:

## Tam.: 100 ÷ 2 = 50

Guardamos esse valor(50) na variável **P** e lançamos na condição `if`.

```
A.onscroll = new Function("
   if(B.style.top = A.scrollTop + P) return true
");
```

Logo o `scroll` que esta ligado ao elemento `div`(primária), for deslizado

A cada "1px" será chamado a `new Function()` para a execução

Que seguido da condição `if`, entra em ação pela sua posição

E num piscar de olhos retorna `true`(reposicionamento realizado).

Pronto!

Answer (score 2):

Como o amigo @Cʜᴜɴ comentou, apenas alterando de `position:absolute;` para `position:fixed;` a `div` central(vermelha) se mantem fixa, e alterei a posição(top,left) p/ manter ela no centro.

```css
#Pai {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
 height: 200px;
 border: 3px solid blue;
 text-align: center;
 overflow: auto;
}

#Filho {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 margin-left: -50px;
 /* metade da largura */
 margin-top: -50px;
 /* metade da altura */
 position: fixed; /* alterei aqui */
 top: 30% ; /* alterei aqui */
 left: 200px ; /* alterei aqui */
 background: tomato;
 z-index: 1; // sobrepor
 -moz-opacity: 0.8;
 opacity: .80;
 filter: alpha(opacity = 80);
}
```

```html
<div id='Pai'>
  
 <p>Elemento A</p>
    <p>Elemento B</p>
    <p>Elemento C</p>
    <p>Elemento D</p>
    <p>Elemento E</p>
    <p>Elemento F</p>
    <p>Elemento G</p>
    <p>Elemento H</p>
    <p>Elemento I</p>
    <p>Elemento J</p>

    <div id='Filho'></div>

</div>
```

Um script sem precisar alterar o css, utilizando **jquery**

```
$("#Pai").scroll(function() {
  console.log($("#Pai").scrollTop());
  $("#Filho").css("top", $("#Pai").scrollTop() + 100);
});
```

Utilizando o mesmo exemplo, agora a div filho é reposicionada conforme o valor do .scrollTop() da div pai, que retorna a posição vertical atual da barra de rolagem, coloquei +100 simplesmente p/ manter centralizada, tu pode alterar o valor tranquilamente p/ ver como se comporta, nota que ao scrollar o body não afeta a posição da div filho.

[Demo - jquery](https://jsfiddle.net/mathiasfcx/6wv056m7/)

Comment: @DiegoHenrique, 3 linhas somente no css, ta comentado no código =)

Comment: Um elemento fixo - `fixed` - é posicionado relativamente ao "viewport", isso significa que ele sempre ficará no mesmo lugar mesmo que haja rolagem na página.

Um detalhe aqui é quando um elemento recebe `position:fixed`, ele fica livre/independente não somente do seu parente, mas do documento como um todo.

Ou seja o elemento `position:fixed` se mantém sempre fixo à janela e não ao elemento em que ele está inserido.

Me parece que temos de setar os valores das propriedades `top` e `left` em "pixel" e utilizar o elemento fixo - `fixed`.

Comment: O elemento `position:fixed` não se adequa muito bem à minha necessidade, o `position` que melhor se adequaria seria o `position:absolute`. Mas sua resposta ja ta valendo. =)

Comment: Realmente, se o elemento pai da div pai possuir scroll a div central(filho) vai acompanhar o scroll, p/ esse caso acho que seria interessante colocar uma função $("#Pai").scroll(function() {..}); que ao scrollar a div pai, movimentar a div filho, com position:absolute; obviamente, se tu achar necessário posso implementar na resposta.

Comment: @DiegoHenrique, da uma olhada aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/mathiasfcx/sac5sL3u/ peguei o mesmo exemplo, coloquei position:abosulte na div filho e uma função na div pai, que ao scrollar a div pai a div filho é reposicionada conforme o valor do .scrollTop(); que retorna a posição vertical atual da barra de rolagem, coloquei +100 simplesmente para centralizada, tu pode alterar o valor tranquilamente p/ ver como se comporta,coloquei um body com scroll p/ mostrar que o scroll não vai afetar a div filho, qualquer duvida só chamar.

Answer (score 1):

você pode usar o evento `scroll` como mencionou, porém o valor do top deve levar em consideração os 50% iniciais.

Abaixo segue um exemplo.

```js
Modernizr.addTest('csscalc', function() {
    var prop = 'width:';
    var value = 'calc(10px);';
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.style.cssText = prop + Modernizr._prefixes.join(value + prop);
    return !!el.style.length;
});

Modernizr.addTest('mozcsscalc', function() {
    var prop = 'width:';
    var value = '-moz-calc(10px);';
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.style.cssText = prop + Modernizr._prefixes.join(value + prop);
    return !!el.style.length;
});


var pai = document.getElementById("Pai");
var filho = document.getElementById("Filho");
pai.addEventListener("scroll", function (e) {
  if (Modernizr.csscalc) {
    filho.style.top = "calc(50% + " + pai.scrollTop + "px)"
  } else if (Modernizr.mozcsscalc) {
    filho.style.top = "-moz-calc(50% + " + pai.scrollTop + "px)"
  }
});
```

```css
#Pai {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

#Filho {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: tomato;
  z-index: 1; // sobrepor
  -moz-opacity: 0.8;
  opacity: .80;
  filter: alpha(opacity = 80);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.js"></script>
<div id='Pai'>  
<p>Elemento A</p>
  <p>Elemento B</p>
  <p>Elemento C</p>
  <p>Elemento D</p>
  <p>Elemento E</p>
  <p>Elemento F</p>
  <p>Elemento G</p>
  <p>Elemento H</p>
  <p>Elemento I</p>
  <p>Elemento J</p>
  <div id='Filho'></div>
</div>
```

P.S.: você não precisa de uma margem negativa para ajustar a posição da div, para tal você pode usar um translate de -50%.

Comment: Estou a utilizar um Firefox 11 numa plataforma DLinux, e não rolou. Em qual Navegador desenvolveu?

Comment: Estou utilizando o Opera

Comment: @DiegoHenrique qual a necessidade de utilizar um Navegador que foi lançado a 5 anos e não tem mais suporte por parte da Mozilla?

Comment: @DiegoHenrique adicionei um fallback para o Mozilla 11, mas aconselho que atualize o seu browser, ou pelo menos avise que esta usando um Browser pré-histórico na hora de fazer a pergunta.

Comment: Bom, Linux são robusto, mas quando ha necessidade de instalar seus pacotes, muita das vezes ocorre alguns conflito entre bibliotecas. Ai começa a correria pra solucionar, pois em muitos caso temos que compilar tudo na unha. Mas tenho o Slax com Firefox 38, e sei que o Firefox ja esta na sua versão 52+ . Mas para cada nova atualização requer na maioria das vezes uma nova máquina. Infelizmente não é somente eu, mas ha outros usuários sem PC novos, ainda mais na crise. E pensando assim, gosto de programar tudo portável, semântica amplamente compatível com os mais de 40 navegadores